# C# WinForms Radio Buttons

Tags: c#

I loaded 4 radios buttons and when I run the program and click on them, if i click one, and click another the other ones goes away. What if I wanted to ahve two radio buttons but they did different things?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Group the different choice sets in separate group boxes (or panels, or other container controls, but group boxes are probably what you're after).

[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-group-windows-forms-radiobutton-controls-to-function-as-a-set):

> Windows Forms RadioButton controls are designed to give users a choice among two or more settings, of which only one can be assigned to a procedure or object. For example, a group of RadioButton controls may display a choice of package carriers for an order, but only one of the carriers will be used. Therefore only one RadioButton at a time can be selected, even if it is a part of a functional group.
>
> You group radio buttons by drawing them inside a container such as a Panel control, a GroupBox control, or a form.

This assumes you have four or more radio buttons on your form. If you have only two, say, and you want to allow the user the possibility of selecting both, use a set of checkboxes.

Answer (score 16):

You should use GroupBox control.
All radio buttons in a GroupBox are mutually exclusive - put 2 radio buttons in one GroupBox, and the other 2 in another GroupBox.
If you don't like your container to be visible - use Panel control instead of GroupBox.
(Just drag and drop)

[image]

As you can probably guess, the upper one is a GroupBox, the lower one (which is invisble, but allows only one readioButton within it to be selected) is a panel.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

I like the concept of grouping RadioButtons in WPF. There is a property `GroupName` that specifies which RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx).

So I wrote a derived class for WinForms that supports this feature:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Use.your.own
{
    public class AdvancedRadioButton : CheckBox
    {
        public enum Level { Parent, Form };

        [Category("AdvancedRadioButton"),
        Description("Gets or sets the level that specifies which RadioButton controls are affected."),
        DefaultValue(Level.Parent)]
        public Level GroupNameLevel { get; set; }

        [Category("AdvancedRadioButton"),
        Description("Gets or sets the name that specifies which RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive.")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCheckedChanged(e);

            if (Checked)
            {
                var arbControls = (dynamic)null;
                switch (GroupNameLevel)
                {
                    case Level.Parent:
                        if (this.Parent != null)
                            arbControls = GetAll(this.Parent, typeof(AdvancedRadioButton));
                        break;
                    case Level.Form:
                        Form form = this.FindForm();
                        if (form != null)
                            arbControls = GetAll(this.FindForm(), typeof(AdvancedRadioButton));
                        break;
                }
                if (arbControls != null)
                    foreach (Control control in arbControls)
                        if (control != this &&
                            (control as AdvancedRadioButton).GroupName == this.GroupName)
                            (control as AdvancedRadioButton).Checked = false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Checked)
                base.OnClick(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawParentBackground(pevent.Graphics, pevent.ClipRectangle, this);

            RadioButtonState radioButtonState;
            if (Checked)
            {
                radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal;
                if (Focused)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.CheckedHot;
                if (!Enabled)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.CheckedDisabled;
            }
            else
            {
                radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal;
                if (Focused)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.UncheckedHot;
                if (!Enabled)
                    radioButtonState = RadioButtonState.UncheckedDisabled;
            }

            Size glyphSize = RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(pevent.Graphics, radioButtonState);
            Rectangle rect = pevent.ClipRectangle;
            rect.Width -= glyphSize.Width;
            rect.Location = new Point(rect.Left + glyphSize.Width, rect.Top);

            RadioButtonRenderer.DrawRadioButton(pevent.Graphics, new System.Drawing.Point(0, rect.Height / 2 - glyphSize.Height / 2), rect, this.Text, this.Font, this.Focused, radioButtonState);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try placing similar options in a container, like GroupBox

Answer (score 2):

Typically a group of radio buttons is used when only one option applies.  If it is valid to select multiple options simultaneously, use Checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Put all radio buttons into a group box.

Now, on all radio button Properties, set `Auto Check` to `false`.

Alternatively, you can set

```
radioButton1->AutoCheck = false;
```

Inside the `radioButton1_Click` function, handle as you needed. Example:

```
Void radioButton1_Click(Object^  sender, EventArgs^  e) {
                radioButton1->Enabled = true;
                radioButton2->Enabled = true;
                radioButton3->Enabled = true;
                radioButton1->Checked = true;
                radioButton2->Checked = true;
                radioButton3->Checked = true;
}
```

This should make those selected radio buttons to check.