# RadioButtons in the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a form which includes 8 radio buttons.
I wanna division these Radio buttons by 2. Look at the picture in the link below then you should understand.

[image: Look at this picture]

You can see 4 Radio buttons in the down to the bottom and left and also you can see 4 Radio buttons in the down to the each pictures in the middle of the form.

Now when i wanna when user select Radio buttons which you can see in the GroupBox on the left side and corner i don't wanna affect on the Radio Buttons on the down to the picture boxes.

I wish you understand what am i trying to say.
I want user's to choose two RadioButtons.
First radio buttons in the Group Box and second Radio Buttons in the down to the picture Boxes.

Comment: Put each group of radio buttons inside a different form... <form action="">1, 2, 3</form> <form action="">4, 5, 6</form> etc

Comment: You need to put them in different `Panel`s or `GroupBox`es (or any other container control). There can only be one checked RadioButton in a container.

Comment: [How to: Group Windows Forms RadioButton Controls to Function as a Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sefz7fxc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As René says you can put them in some kind of container like a Panel or GroupBox, or as an alternative you can simply set the [GroupName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WinForms Radio Buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851765/c-sharp-winforms-radio-buttons)

Comment: _you can see 4 Radio buttons at the bottom to the each pictures in the middle of the form_  No. I can't see that.