# a single radio button check between several

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have a datagrid that imports data and this data is affiliated with columns, my concern is that I have 2 radio buttons and I would like when I select a radio button the other on the same line is automatically deselected. I tried to find the solution but still no find so I ask for your help Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make mutually Exclusive checkBoxes in WPF DataGrid Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987146/how-to-make-mutually-exclusive-checkboxes-in-wpf-datagrid-columns)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what UI framework you use:

For WinForms:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851776/18990321

For WPF:

You should use the GroupName property.

https://wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-radiobutton-control/